# Python How hide show error Message and Warnings when execute .exe

Tags: python-3.x, console, pyinstaller, hide, suppress-warnings

[IMAGE OF ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8quF4.png)

When execute .exe show this IMAGE ERROR above. But the program is working properly, i need hide this show message and hide warnings i compiled used this code `pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile Main.py`

**How i hide this message error, warnings and console ?**

*fast1.py line 1085*

`("stdin", sys.stdin.encoding),`

*Main.py line 41*

````
        classFast = fast1
        classFast.main()```
````

Comment: you don't, you need to fix the bug in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix the bug in the code in order to get rid of the error window.

Whatever code you are running has no `stdin` so I am assuming it is a GUI program with no attached console.  Therefore when you call `sys.stdin` it returns `None`, and `NoneType` object has no attribute `encoding`.

So the solution would either be to remove that line or use a conditional expression that tests if `sys.stdin` is None before running it.

For Exampl:

```
if `sys.stdin` is not None:
    ("stdin", sys.stdin.encoding)
```